# Truncating the data create the snapshot in Cassandra consuming unnecessary space

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1

I had a column family containing the space of 40GB. I truncated the column family. So, after `GC_GRACE_SECONDS` Cassandra created snapshots of the truncated data which is consuming the same amount of space. Is there any way by means of which we can get rid of space utilized by snapshots without disable the creation of snapshots. I mean isn't there any timeout parameter after which it will delete the snapshot consuming unnecessary space.

Answer (score 3):

The snapshot that you are seeing getting created after truncating the column family is actually a safety mechanism in C* to avoid mass data loss in case of accidental table delete or  truncation (btw it has nothing to do with gc_grace_seconds). There is a setting 'auto_snapshot' in cassandra.yaml which is true by default. From DataStax documentation

*auto_snapshot 
(Default: true ) Enable or disable whether a snapshot is taken of the data before keyspace truncation or dropping of tables. To prevent data loss, using the default setting is strongly advised. If you set to false, you will lose data on truncation or drop.*

If you want to delete snapshots then you can use *nodetool clearsnapshot* command as explained [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsClearSnapShot.html)